# How can I output the current rendered component when using the React testing library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to understand whether or not some DOM removed from rendered component. So how do I do current component HTML output into VSCode console just to see what actually rendered. Here is my simple test. I want to do something like: `console.log(renderer.<page content>)`

```
import { render, fireEvent, waitForElementToBeRemoved } from '@testing-library/react'


it ('test', async () => {
   const renderer = render(<MyComponent />)

   fireEvent.click(renderer.getByText('Click to Hide'))

   await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => renderer.getByText('text to hide'))
})
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
import { render, fireEvent, waitForElementToBeRemoved, prettyDOM } from '@testing-library/react'


it ('test', async () => {
   const renderer = render(<MyComponent />)

   ...

   console.log(prettyDOM(renderer.container.firstChild))
```

Answer (score 14):

`screen.debug()` is a quick way to do it.  Most tests usually have screen imported to begin with.

> For convenience screen also exposes a debug method in addition to the
> queries. This method is essentially a shortcut for
> console.log(prettyDOM()). It supports debugging the document, a single
> element, or an array of elements.

[Docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging#screendebug)

Answer (score 1):

For me `screen.debug()` or any `console.log()` statements were not printing any output. And as per the [documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/#screendebug)

> For convenience screen also exposes a debug method. This method is essentially a shortcut for console.log(prettyDOM()).

So I changed it to `console.debug(prettyDOM())` and it started printing output in the console.